# Stretch or resample 1D array

Tags: c#, arrays, int

This question might be something really simple and I might be missing something really basic, but how do you interpolate a 1D array in C#?

Lets say I have this array of n elements

```
int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 1 };
```

How to stretch or compress the array so that it has n values and interpolates the values, just like when you resize an image, thats it, not chopping or adding zeros or empty values to the array.

For example if I want to convert the array so it  has n = 4 elements, get this

```
array1
>>[2, 4, 6, 4]
```

[image: Strech example]

what I'm trying to do is the same as the resample function from matlab does
https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html

Comment: I don't understand how you got from the first array to the second one. Did you take the first n elements and add 1 to them? Something else?

Comment: What is the calculation you are looking for? What is stretch supose to do?

Comment: @mjwills It seems to be an average of 1 and 3, 3 and 5, etc.

Comment: @Boris - it might be, but we really need the OP to confirm that. There are **many** ways I can think of to get from the first to the second.

Comment: yes in that case it'll be an average of the the values, It might be easy to imagine it as a 1xn pixels (array) image that I want to resize to a 1xm size (array) image

Comment: Please show us at least 7 other sample inputs and the expected results for those inputs. Ensure that some of the inputs don't have numbers that are exactly 2 apart from each other. Also explain what `n` is for.

Comment: Are you looking for something as the equivalent to a feature of another language?

Comment: Ok, when you decrease the length by 1, you want the average of consecutive numbers (but what is the average of 1 and 2?). What if you want to decrease the length by 3? What about increasing the length by 1 or 3?

Comment: just as when you resize an image, but this case in 1D instead of 2D

Comment: Please add the sample inputs as requested.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is the same as the resample function from matlab does
https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html

Comment: There's a C++ version [here](https://github.com/terrygta/SignalResampler) if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this solution for the case that the new array is shorter than the old one:

```
int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
int[] array2 = new int[4];

for (var i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
{
    var doubleIndex1 = (double)i * array1.Length / array2.Length;
    var index1 = (int)Math.Floor(doubleIndex1);
    var rel = doubleIndex1 - index1;

    array2[i] = (int)Math.Round((1.0 - rel) * array1[index1] + rel * array1[index1 + 1]);
}
```

Comment: yeah, it works that way but only when the values in the array are linearly growing or decreasing, 
thanks anyway

Comment: Well yes, this is linear interpolation. Do you need someting more sophisticated? Then have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation

Comment: @Boris that's what you get for not providing a good set of examples when asked to.

Comment: just a resize dude, as when you stretch or shrink an image, I really dont get whats so hard to understand, I feel like I'm speaking a totally different language from anyone else, dont know how else to explain it, sorry

Comment: Also when streching or shrinking an image, there are many different ways to do it. See e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.bitmapscalingmode?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Boris as a programmer and an amateur photographer, I'll tell you that when it comes to resizing an image Photoshop gives me a lot of resampling options, including: bicubic, nearest neighbour, and bilinear. There are a vast number of interpolation algorithms, etc. With a single example, it's impossible to tell which one you want. Klaus believed that linear was the method you wanted, now you're saying it's not.